# Retrieve data from multiple columns and display within a single column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL2005.

I would like to retrieve data from multiple columns and merge them, separating them by comma.

E.g. Data in my SQL Table *UserData*:

`No. | Username | Role 1 | Role 2   | Role 3 |`

`1   | Jimmy    | USER   | READONLY | WRITE  |`

Data I would like to display in my GridView *GridView1*:

`No. | Username | Roles |`

`1   | Jimmy    | USER, READONLY, WRITE |`

How can I use a SELECT statement to merge data from the 3 columns and merge them, separating the data by commas and list them in the GridView?

Thank you

---

**EDIT**

I have tried using the method provided by Shark and Mun, but I would like to remove the commas if the data in a Role column is empty.

Situation now is that `Roles` column will look like this if Role 2 and Role 3 is empty:
`USER,,`

May I know how can I group `,` into the variable as well so it will not display if the value is empty?

Comment: You may need to check for null, as concatenating columns with null values will result in a null value.  Try this SQL query instead: select username, IsNull([role 1], '') + ', ' + IsNull([role 2], '') + ', ' + IsNull([role 3], '') as Roles from UserData

Comment: @RUiHAO Check out my edited post.  It uses `ISNULL()` to get your desired result.

Comment: @Mun that query will put a leading comma or double commas with different NULL values.  Check out my answer.  Combine the column and the comma character in the `ISNULL()` function and that should be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @RUiHAO I see your edit.  See my updated answer, that new query and code should give you your desired result.

Comment: @Shark Looks good. Haven't come across NullIf command before, but that's definitely something that I can see myself using in future.  Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the SQL query:

```
select
    username,
    isnull(nullif([role 1], '') + ', ', '') + 
    isnull(nullif([role 2], '') + ', ', '') + 
    isnull(nullif([role 3], ''), '') as Roles
from UserData
```

And then for your grid view code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionStringHere);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = 
    "select " +
    "    username, " +
    "    isnull(nullif([role 1], '') + ', ', '') + " +
    "    isnull(nullif([role 2], '') + ', ', '') + " +
    "    isnull(nullif([role 3], ''), '') as Roles " +
    "from UserData";

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
Datatable YourData = new DataTable();

try
{
    sda.Fill(YourData);

    GridView1.DataSource = YourData;
    GridView1.Bind();
}
catch
{
    sda.Dispose();
    // handle your error
}
```

Comment: hi, I have implemented the method. However is there a way to remove `,` if the value is empty? I am having some trouble with the display of data whenever Role 1,2 or 3 is empty, `,` are displayed as well

Comment: @RUiHAO That's exactly what that query will do.  It Checks for the combination of `[role x] + ', '`.  If that is `NULL` (which it will be if `[role x]` is `NULL`), then it won't show the unnecessary comma.

Comment: @RUiHAO When you say "empty", what do you mean?  `NULL` or a blank string (`''`)??  Those are two very different things.  The above solution is for `NULL` values, not an empty string (`''`).

Comment: @RUiHAO See my edit.  This will handle the situation where your `[role x]` field is `NULL` or an empty string.  Let me know if that works out for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this in stored procedure, and then bind GridView to that stored procedure:

```
SELECT No., Username, CAST(Role1 AS varchar(1024)+ ', ' + Role2 + ', ' + Role3)
```